# Enable virtualization (Vt/x) from VirtualBox - Install 64-bits virtual machine

Tags: gnome, virtualbox, 64-bit, virtualization

I'm having trouble with VirtualBox within Ubuntu. I want to create a 64-bit virtual machine, but VB only gives me 32-bit options (see [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nCKlR.png)). I installed VirtualBox on macOS, and it works fine. However, when I installed VB within Ubuntu I got this problem.

In fact, I wanted to install `gnome-software` (with Virtualbox) on Ubuntu in following this [YouTube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gqAXRqqUnpE), but it is not possible so far.

I have a Macbook Pro (Mid-2012, 13-inch), and Ubuntu 64-bit with installed with VirtualBox

The problem seems to be the Vt/x is disabled. I thought it was the one on the OS X. According to the Apple Support, it couldn't be modified from OS X. So we have to enable from VB.

**Question :** Could anyone be able to tell me how to enable virtualization from VB?

P.S. It is a bit weird, but I installed Ubuntu with VB on macOS, and now I want to install gnome-software with VB within Ubuntu.

Comment: Just to clarify: Host OS is OSX, hardware is Apple, and Vt/x is enabled in BIOS? Do you dual boot OSX and Ubuntu? What version and architecture of Ubuntu would that be?

Comment: @Takkat - Macs don't have a BIOS.

Comment: I know, it is a UEFI or just EFI boot.

Comment: Still unclear. Do you try to set up a nested VM? This is at present only possible with software virtualization (i.e. 32-bit). See https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/4032

Answer (score -1):

Try this link https://forum.parallels.com/threads/how-to-enable-vt-aka-vtx-or-vt-x-with-refit-and-vmx-var-set-efi.3273/ It should work.